# Возможен ли на Node.js запуск приложения с GUI без скачивания дополнительного ПО?

Tags: node.js, nw.js

Мне нужно создать нативное приложение на Node.js, работающее по следующему принципу: после глобальной установки этого приложения как обычного npm-пакета (`npm i my-app -g`), при вводе `my-app start` в консоль приложение запускается и появляется графический интерфейс. Графический интерфейс нативный, то есть браузер не используется. Естественно, данное приложение может работать с файлами и папками.

Про `NW.js` я слышал. Вероятно, я что-то неправильно понял, но если я не ошибаюсь, то для того, чтобы **запустить** приложение на `NW.js`, надо скачивать и устанавливать данное программное обеспечение, причём делается это не так, как установка обычной npm-библиотеки. Если это так, то заставлять пользователей ещё что-то скачивать - значить бесить пользователей, а меня это не устраивает: надо, чтобы всё работало только от `npm i my-app -g` и `my-app start` без скачивания и установки каких-то дополнительных приложений. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Не до конца понял точно что нужно, ну гуй можно с помощью `electron` написать. Это нпм пакет, если что :) На npmjs.com лежит.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, Благодарю Вас за рекомендацию! Вы бы не могли сказать, какую конкретно фразу Вы не поняли, чтобы я исправил вопрос?

Comment: Я не понял, нужно написать какой-то специфически работающий из под консоли софт с возможностью использовать гуй, или просто нужно написать гуёвый софт на JS. Если последнее, то электрон. Но на вас будут пальцем показывать и говорить, какой вы нехороший человек. Редиска! Но вы не слушайте! :)

Comment: @AlexSazonov, вообще-то второе, но пуск приложения производится не кликом по иконке этого приложения, а консольной командой `my-app start`. ">Но вы не слушайте!" Спасибо за предупреждение!^^ Если никто ничего не сможет предложить лучше для решения задачи, то подобные обвинения будут лишены логических оснований.

Comment: `заставлять пользователей ещё что-то скачивать - значить бесить пользователей` - странное утверждение. Намного ведь удобнее кликнуть на иконку приложения в панели инструментов и запустить программу, чем открывать терминал и что-то там писать

Comment: @Дмытрык, Вы правы. Вот только бы заменить две установки (NW.js + библиотека) одной.

Comment: Всмысле, две установки? Не знаю как NW.js, Electron создает десктопное приложение `.exe`. Пользователь его скачивает 1 раз, устанавливает 1 раз  - и все. Иконка приложения появляется в меню Пуск, его можно разместить на Панели задач и т.д. VSCode, Skype - написаны на Electron'e

Comment: @Дмытрык, ладно, в любом случае, спасибо за комментарий; буду пробовать.